# Unit testing classes that implement a collection Interface?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I've written a storage interface that can use different storage backends. As a demonstration I've written an implementation that stores objects as a key/value pair in a standard Python dictionary.

```
class MyStorageInterface(object):
    def store(self, key, value):
        raise NotImplementedError("Class must be subclassed")

    def get(self, key):
        raise NotImplementedError("Class must be subclassed")

# Example implementation
class DictStorage(MyStorageInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        self._cache = dict()

    def store(self, key, value):
        self._cache[key] = value

    def get(self, key):
        return self._cache[key]
```

Now, I want to write some unit tests for my `DictStorage` implementation. My question is whether or not something like:

```
storage = DictStorage()
value = 8
key = 'foo'
storage.store(key, value)
actual = storage.get(key)
assert actual == 8, "cache value for %s is %s, expected %s" % (key, str(actual), str(value))
```

is a suitable unit test for the get method or whether or not there is a Pythonic pattern for testing classes that implement collection type objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's anything "collection-specific" but the structure of your test looks good to me. The only difference is that I'd make use of the `unittest` package and define it as test case:

```
import unittest


class MyStorageInterface(object):
    def store(self, key, value):
        raise NotImplementedError("Class must be subclassed")

    def get(self, key):
        raise NotImplementedError("Class must be subclassed")


class DictStorage(MyStorageInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        self._cache = dict()

    def store(self, key, value):
        self._cache[key] = value

    def get(self, key):
        return self._cache[key]


class DictStorageTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self._sut = DictStorage()

    def test_storing_and_retrieving_value(self):
        value_in = 8
        key = 'foo'
        self._sut.store(key, value_in)
        value_out = self._sut.get(key)
        self.assertEqual(value_in, value_out)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**Output**

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```